# Data is delayed by one while passing from child component to parent

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

i have two component `App` and `Child` .And whenever there's a **change** in the input field of the `Child`  component it should update the change in the `App` component instantly.
But rather than updating the `App` instantly it is one step behind.
here is the code :-

App component

```
function App() {
  const [ChildData, setChildData] = useState("");
  
  
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <Child passdata={setChldData}/>
      </div>
      <div>
        {ChildData.name}
      </div>
      
    </div>
  )
}
```

Child component

```
function Child(props) {
    const [Data, setData] = useState({ name:'' ,title:'' ,phone:'' });
  
    const handleChange = (e)=>{
        setData({...Data, [e.target.name] : e.target.value})
        props.passdata(Data)
    }
  
    return (
    <div>
      <h2>Child Data</h2>
      <input type="text" name='name' onChange={handleChange} placeholder={"Name"}/>
      <input type="text" name='title' onChange={handleChange} placeholder={"Title"}/>
      <input type="number" name='phone' onChange={handleChange} placeholder={"Phone number"}/>

    </div>
  )
}
```

Whenever there;s a change in the input field it is one step behind.
i want the `App` component change simultaneously with the input from `Child`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Comment: yes. but it would be nice if you have something simpler than that ; ) .

Comment: "Simpler" how?  The value you're looking to send to `props.passdata` is `{...Data, [e.target.name] : e.target.value}`, not `Data`.  That's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function Child(props) {
    const [Data, setData] = useState({ name:'' ,title:'' ,phone:'' });
  
    const handleChange = (e)=>{
        setData((prevData) => {
            const newData = {...prevData, [e.target.name] : e.target.value}
            props.passData(newData)
            return newData
        })
    }
  
    return (
    <div>
      <h2>Child Data</h2>
      <input type="text" name='name' value={data.name} onChange={handleChange} placeholder={"Name"}/>
      <input type="text" name='title' value={data.title} onChange={handleChange} placeholder={"Title"}/>
      <input type="number" name='phone' value={data.phone} onChange={handleChange} placeholder={"Phone number"}/>

    </div>
  )
}
```

By the way you also forgot to bind `value` on the fields so changes in the state from somewhere other than typing in the box wouldn't have been reflected. I've fixed that too.

Additionally what you are doing looks like a code smell. You generally don't want to duplicate state in two places. Instead, you should have one canonical truth. What is the point in the copy that exists in child if you can just pass it back down from the parent?